# Find the initial point of a vector given the location and direction of the terminal point

Tags: vectors

Hopefully someone can help me understand what I'm missing.

The question in full is: "Find the initial point P of a vector u with terminal Q(3,0,-5) in the same direction as V(4,-2,-1)".

I understand how to find the direction from V, but without the magnitude of u how can I know the initial point? Isn't there infinitely many possible initial points given only direction?

Thanks

Comment: I think you are indeed missing the length of the vector $u$: you know that its endpoint is $(3,0,-5)$ and that it lies on a straight line parallel to $\{(4t,-2t,-t)\,:\,t\in\Bbb R\}$. But this is not sufficient.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Thanks for your input. I figured this was the case, but was hoping it wasn't considering this is for a piece of university assessment. I will probably just write something similar to what you have written.